# Access Spring Boot Hibernate session, to unproxy detached object

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I need to unproxy a detached Hibernate object in a Spring Boot 3, Hibernate 6 environment. Method:

```java
 @Autowired
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 @Transactional 
 public <T> T loadUnproxied(T object) {
    if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(object)) {
      Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

      // Reattach detached entity to a session.
      // Here it fails:
      session.merge(object);

      Hibernate.initialize(object);
    }
    return object;
 }
```

This leads always to this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister:
org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag
```

The suggested solutions for this are basically to fix the entity-scan, but the entity detection is fine, Spring manages this fine, persistence is otherwise working. It seems my code opens a 2nd route for Hibernate, bypassing the Spring persistence. But I need access to Spring sessions, which did the scan already. The `@Transactional` doesn't seem to help.

**What I won't do, is loading the incoming `object` as an EAGER fetch *before* calling `loadUnproxied(...)`.** The whole concept is to pass around lazy loaded objects, and load only needed data on demand.

(I'm really very thankful for any help, but other similiar questions I found, were people mentioned they want still to use LAZY loading, were flooded with answers how to disable LAZY loading.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, there are 2 problems and solutions:

1. `session.merge(object)`. It must be `session.update(object)`. `update` was actually my first choice, but that's deprecated and Hibernate tells to use `merge` instead. But `merge` doesn't work. It doesn't reattach the `object` to the session.
2. The exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag` becomes understandable when debugging Hibernate. It happens when trying to unproxy a list, which is stored in a `org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentBag`. Hibernate has no data on how to reinitialize that list, after it got detached. Only entities can be reinitialized / unproxied. The only solution to unproxy lists I found, was to completely reload the container entity, and initialize the list in that transactions session.

Solution:

```java
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public <T> T loadUnproxied(T object) {
  if (!Hibernate.isInitialized(object)) {
    if (object instanceof PersistentBag) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Can't unproxy list out of session");
    }

    final SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(
      SessionFactory.class
    );

    sessionFactory.inTransaction((Session session) -> {
      session.update(object);
      Hibernate.initialize(object);
    });
  }
  return object;
}
```

Comment: If update is deprecated and merge should be used, it might be that you need to change the code more than just substitute the update call with a merge call. This is a temporary fix, but you are risking to have to change your code again quite soon.